# Select from column where value starts with 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table T

```
id    val1
a      199.87
b      166.56
c      100.67
d      233.45
e      177.23
```

1. I want to select those rows where `val1` starts with 1
2. rows where `val1` starts with 19.

Is there any way of doing this in SQL Server.

The data type of val1 is float.

Comment: Can you add some background about the purpose and meaning of the data? Converting to varchar makes the query non sargable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) I want to select those rows where val1 starts with 1

```
SELECT
  *
FROM Table_1
WHERE val1 LIKE '1%'
```

[image: output1]

2) rows where val1 starts with 19.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM Table_1
WHERE val1 LIKE '19%'
```

[image: output2]

Comment: Surely in your last query, the first predicate is redundant

Answer (score 1):

Use like operator to get your results. No need to convert datatype of Val1.

1. rows where val1 starts with 1:

SELECT * FROM T WHERE val1 LIKE '1%';

2. rows where val1 starts with 19:

SELECT * FROM T WHERE val1 LIKE '19%';

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `LIKE %` conditioning when filtering results you selct from the table and so it goes like this.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE STR(VAL1, 10, 5) LIKE '19%'
```

This works for me whenever I select a row containing a specific char or number of a column containing value.

EDIT: Used [STR()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql) function to convert numeric data into character data.

Comment: You should not use `LIKE` with floats - convert it to string type first.

Comment: your're right sorry forgot to convert it to string first so it would not come in handy. Thank you for the Correction.

Comment: Feel free to edit your answer to include this information

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONVERT` or `cast` function in where clause to cast `float` to `character` data type . Below queries will generate your desired result.

```
select * from table1
where convert(varchar,val) like '1%';

select * from table1
where cast(val as char(10)) like '1%';
```

You can use anyone of the above.

**Result**

```
id  val
-----------
a   199,87
b   166,56
c   100,67
e   177,23
```

To return `val` like `19`, just replace `1` with `19`.

You can check the demo [here](http://rextester.com/EGIXDA55131)

Comment: Caution though:  this makes it impossible to use any indexes on val1

Comment: @CaiusJard: yes, conversion should be done if there is no other way around like the one you mentioned in your answer. Thanks for the tip :-) .

Answer (score 0):

If your data values will never exceed 200 it would be preferable not to convert them to another data type just to answer this query. Instead leave them as floats and assess them using a range comparison

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE val1 >= 100 AND val1 < 200
```

Similarly for 19x.xx values, make it `>= 190`

Avoid converting data wherever possible; it adds overhead which affects query performance, and also means that indexes cannot be used - this can massively impact the performance of a query

Answer (score 0):

This question already has many good answers, below answer is a  different approach.

```
create table table1(
    id char(10),
    val float

);    

insert into table1 values('a',199.87);
insert into table1 values('b',166.56);
insert into table1 values('c',100.67);
insert into table1 values('d',233.45);
insert into table1 values('e',177.23);



Query
select * from table1 where (CHARINDEX( '1',val, 1))=1;
select * from table1 where (CHARINDEX( '19',val, 1))=1;

output 
    id  val
    a           199,87
    b           166,56
    c           100,67
    e           177,23

    id  val
    a           199,87
```